# What does the start command actually do?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, environment-variables

Suppose I want to launch a program from the **cmd** (or **windows powershell**). If i simply type the name of the executable of course nothing starts, as my shell does not know where to find the `.exe` that I am referencing. One solution of course is to add the location of my executable in my `PATH` environment variable; however this is annoying, laborious, and also this habit quickly litters the `PATH` variable.

I was looking for better solutions and I stumbled upon the `start` command. In the manual it is said that this command searches my machine (and not just what it's in `PATH`) for the `.exe` that I typed and then runs it. This seems pretty cool and should avoid all the tinkering with `PATH`.

*However* apparently the `start` command works in *mysterious ways*: it opens up *some* executable outside of `PATH` but *not all of them*. I would like to know how `start` searches for `.exe` files in my machine so that I can predict its behaviour more consistently and really start to use this command (pun intended).

So, how does the start command work? Where and how it searches for files? Can I stop littering my `PATH` variable or am I damned to trash it?